# Viewport scale site below 450px

Tags: html, viewport, meta

I have a website with a fluid layout. The width of the content always fills the width of the screen. This is all good down to mobile size where I don't want the width of the body to go below `450px`.

I have `min-width:450px` set on the the body which as expected, stops the body reducing in width below that point. Now the problem I have is on mobiles with a screen size below `450px` the user has to scroll horizontally to see the content out of view.

I want the content to scale down from `450px` using the `viewport` `meta` tag.

I tried this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=450,user-scalable=no">
```

Which works, but it is also applying it to mobiles above `450px` width and iPads too, making it look horribly zoomed in on tablets. Is there a way to use this tag without applying it to anything above `450px`?

Comment: Does the `maximum-scale` [mentioned here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_width_and_screen_width) do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using media-queries instead.

Just place this at the end of your CSS-file and add your special-styles for small devices:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 450px) {
 YOUR STYLES FOR < 450px DEVICES GO HERE
}
```

Comment: No the whole point is that I want the entire site to scale down at mobile size, so it's essentially a 450px layout on things like 320px width screens. That means the font, images, div sizes etc all scale in proportion to each other. This is not really logical with CSS.

Comment: Well styling is pure CSS... separation of markup and style and such ;)
"initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" maybe?
//EDIT: It would be a lot easier with a fiddle/codepen/demo